# Sum of divisor function over arithmetic progression

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-progression, divisors-multiples

I am trying to find an estimate for the following sum:

$$
\sum_{\substack{n \leq x \\ n \equiv k (m)}} d(n),
$$

where $d(n)$ is number of divisors of $n$. I found estimates for the case when $k$ and $m$ are coprime, but nothing explicit for general case. My expectation for this sum is that this should be known, but I can't find anything. Any ideas/references?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the context of the "divisor problem for arithmetical progressions",
there is the following article by Fouvry, Iwaniec and Katz, on "The divisor function over arithmetic progressions": http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa61/aa6134.pdf.
The authors use Fourier series techniques
and Weil’s estimate for Kloosterman sums to obtain 
$$
S(x,m,k)-D(x,m)=\sum_{n\le x, n\equiv k(m)}d(n)-\frac{1}{\phi(m)}\sum_{n\le x,(n,m)=1}d(n)=O((m^{1/2}+x^{1/3})x^{\epsilon}).
$$
We have the estimate 
$$
\phi(m)D(x,m)=\sum_{n\le x,(n,m)=1}d(n)=xP(\log x)+O(x^{1/2}m^{\epsilon}),
$$
with $P(\log x)=\frac{\phi(m)^2}{m^2}(\log x+\gamma-1)+2\frac{\phi(m)}{m}\sum_{d\mid m}\frac{\mu(d)\log d}{d}$.

Werner Georg Nowak proved in $1984$ that for any given natural numbers $m$ and $k$,
$$
S(x,m,k)=\alpha x(\log x+2\gamma -1)+\beta x+ O(x^{35/108+\epsilon}),
$$
for constants $\alpha$ and $\beta$ depending only on $m$ and $k$.

Comment: Are you sure that you have stated the upper bounds correctly? Already for $m=k=1$, it is known that the sum is asymptotic to $x\log x$ as $x \to \infty$. Or are you referring to the error terms in the corresponding Dirichlet divisor problem?

Comment: @DanielLoughran Yes, the difference, sorry. I edited my answer.

Comment: Those authors consider the situation where $m$ and $k$ are coprime.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but this is indeed, as Matt noted, the coprime case

Comment: @PauliusŠarka I don't think so. Nowak's estimates are for all natural numbers $m,k$.

Comment: OK, so the paper in Comment. Math. Univ. ST. Pauli was indeed a spot on reference (see answer and comments below), in turn leading to a paper H. G. Kopetzky, Über die Größenordnung der Teilerfunktion in Restklassen, Monatshefte für Mathematik, 82(4), 1976 for the values of the constants. Thank you Dietrich!

Comment: @PauliusŠarka: You are welcome ! Yes, I have Kopetzky's paper, too. But it is in german (perhaps not a problem for understanding the value of the constants).

Comment: @DietrichBurde where exactly do they obtain your first stated equality?  they state it as (3), but do they prove it explicitly? (/is it implicitly proved somewhere in the paper?)

Answer (score 0):

Werner Georg Nowak, ON A RESULT OF SMITH AND SUBBARAO CONCERNING A DIVISOR PROBLEM
Canad. Math. Bull. Vol. 27 (4), 1984.

Werner considers a different problem. He investigates  the number of (positive) divisors of the positive integer n which are congruent to l modulo k. I.e. d(n;l,k) = #{d : d|n & d ≡ l(k)}.

Comment: No, I mean W. G. Nowak, On the divisor problem in arithmetic progressions, Comment.
Math. Univ. St. Pauli 33 (1984), 209–217.

Comment: where is this paper?  i couldn't find it, not even on the author's website.  all the results i find from him are to do with the quantity $d(n;l,k)$ in this answer and not with $S(x,m,k)$ of your answer.  maybe i'm overlooking something? :)